# Sent data to component

Tags: reactjs

I have a table of data from my API. This table contains a checkbox. if i check the checkbox the data should be sent to another component, where I can compare the values.

I can not find a way how to sent the data to the state of the second component.
The table is created by "materialtable".

I have the table, the event and the array of data but how to put in the other component?
[image]

Can you point me to an easy tutorial where data between components are exchanged?

Thank you very much

Comment: You should **lift your state up** - https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html, or use something like **context** - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: you can use `Context` API or state management like Redux. the main concept in redux is you put the data in a place called store, then set any component to listen to the store changes.

checkbox - update store - compare component listen to the store changes.

you can learn more here https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux